# Can you use AutoDateLocator outside of matplotlib? Nice label algorithm for time axis

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting my own chart by drawing on a canvas object, I struggled with getting a nice date interval that works for all kinds of date ranges perfectly. I though I might use the matplotlib class that can locate the best ticks on the screen estate.

```
from matplotlib.dates import AutoDateLocator
import datetime as dt


a = AutoDateLocator()
r = a.get_locator(dt.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 18, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 19, 0))
# set min, max in pixel estate
# get ticks?
```

I'm also open to use anything else which is great in creating meaningful intervals for different date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
from matplotlib.dates import mdates
import datetime as dt

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(maxticks=100)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

formatter.format_ticks(locator.tick_values(dt.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 18, 0), dt.datetime(2021, 12, 13, 19, 0))))
```

returns

> ['18:00',
> '18:01',
> '18:02',
> '18:03',
> '18:04',
> '18:05',
> '18:06',
> '18:07',
> '18:08',
> '18:09',
> '18:10',
> '18:11',
> '18:12',
> '18:13',
> '18:14',
> '18:15',
> '18:16',
> '18:17',
> '18:18',
> '18:19',
> '18:20',
> '18:21',
> '18:22',
> '18:23',
> '18:24',
> '18:25',
> '18:26',
> '18:27',
> '18:28',
> '18:29',
> '18:30',
> '18:31',
> '18:32',
> '18:33',
> '18:34',
> '18:35',
> '18:36',
> '18:37',
> '18:38',
> '18:39',
> '18:40',
> '18:41',
> '18:42',
> '18:43',
> '18:44',
> '18:45',
> '18:46',
> '18:47',
> '18:48',
> '18:49',
> '18:50',
> '18:51',
> '18:52',
> '18:53',
> '18:54',
> '18:55',
> '18:56',
> '18:57',
> '18:58',
> '18:59',
> '19:00']

Setting `maxticks=10`:

> ['18:00', '18:10', '18:20', '18:30', '18:40', '18:50', '19:00']

And using a years worth date range:

> ['2021', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jul', 'Sep', 'Nov']